# Basic pipeline in c++

Tags: c++, pipeline

I have 3 main procedures written in c/c++:

```
1. Read frame from video stream (using opencv VideoCapture).
2. Process frame (some tracking algorithm).
3. Write frame to new video stream(using opencv Videowriter).
```

I want to construct a "simple" pipeline (using c++11 only) where each core/thread will get responsibility for each procedure as follows:

```
t1: Thread 1 - read frame#1; Thread 2 - do nothing; Thread 3 - do nothing;

t2: Thread 1 - read frame#2; Thread 2 - process frame#1; Thread 3 - do nothing;

t3: Thread 1 - read frame#3; Thread 2 - process frame#2; Thread 3 - write  processed frame#1;

t4: Thread 1 - read frame#4; Thread 2 - process frame#3; Thread 3 - write  processed frame#2;
```

and so on....

Appreciate any help in the steps of doing that.

Comment: This is a very broad question. You can start by reading [this link](http://thispointer.com/c-11-multithreading-part-1-three-different-ways-to-create-threads/)

Comment: I am curious are there asynchronous callbacks available for each stage in opencv?